# Jquery .post () giving error message "missing : after property id"

Tags: jquery, forms, post

I have written a form using the jQuery .post() function to post the data to a php file. The error I keep getting is "missing : after property id". Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the form code:

```
 <form id="ev-form" name="ev-form" action="/new_event_submit.php" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <ol>
                      <li>    
                        <label for="ev-name">Event</label>
                        <input type="text" id="ev-name" name="ev-name" class="text" />
                      </li>
                      <li>  
                        <label for="ev-date">Date &amp; Time</label>
                        <input type="text" id="ev-date" name="ev-date" class="text" />
                      </li>
                      <li>  
                        <label for="ev-desc">Description</label>
                        <textarea id="ev-desc" name="ev-desc" cols="" rows="" class="textarea"></textarea>
                      </li>
                      <li>  
                        <input type="submit" id="ev-submit" value="Submit Event" class="submit" />
                      </li>
                    </ol>
                </fieldset>
                <div id="load-icon"></div>
            </form>
```

The javascript .post() function is as below:

```
$j(document).ready(function(){

//Setup on the click event
   $j('#ev-form input.submit').click(function(){

//Setup some variable with needed values
        var input_name  = $j('input:eq(0)').val(),
        input_date  = $j('input:eq(1)').val(),
        input_desc  = $j('#ev-form textarea').val(),
        ajax_loader = '<img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loader" />';

    //Hide and previous response
    $j('#response').hide();

    //show the loader
    $j('#load-icon').html(ajax_loader);

    $j.post('new_event_submit.php', {ev-name: input_name, ev-date: input_date, ev-desc: input_desc}, function(data) {

        //Hide the loader
        $j('#load-icon img').hide(1000, function() {
            $j('#ev-form').append('<div id="response">' + data + '</div>');
        });

    });
    return false;
});
```

});

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have a hyphens in a key names (e.g. `ev-desc`), unless you encapsulate them in quotes: `'ev-desc'`